# How to make transparency in emgu cv?

Tags: c#, opencv, transparency, emgucv, alpha

I have a requirement of making the black color background of a image as transparent. Any ideas on how to do this using EmguCV ?

Below is the image which I'm using for this process.

[image]

Comment: C++ code here... 1) Convert your image to 4 channels (4th channel is  alpha channel): `cvtColor(imageBGR, imageBGRA, COLOR_BGR2BGRA);`, 2) You have probably a mask of the non-chair. If not, just create one for black pixels: `Mat1b mask; inRange(imageBGR, Scalar(0,0,0), Scalar(0,0,0), mask);` 3) Set alpha channel to 0 (transparent), according to mask: `imageBGRA.setTo(Scalar(0,0,0,0), mask);`. 4) Done! 5) Happy porting in C# :D 6) remember to save as png, or other formats that support alpha channels

Comment: @Miki Thank you for your response :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First keep in mind that some image types do not support transparency, for example jpeg,

What you're describing is easy to implement; just iterate through the pixels and when you encounter a black pixel (all rgb values are less then 10), replace it with a new pixel (or MCvScalar in emgucv) with an alpha value set to zero.

> (255, 255, 255, 0)

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Haimovitz, I tried converting the image to bitmap and by iterating and replacing the pixel with <bitmap image>.SetPixel(w, h, Color.Transparent); and saved it to png. That worked!

Comment: I tried with the MCvScalar modification approach as well. src[h, w].MCvScalar = new MCvScalar(255, 255, 255, 0); but that resulted in an error saying that "Cannot modify the return value of 'Emgu.CV.Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr,byte>.this[int, int]' because it is not a variable"

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, happy it worked out for you.